# Java reflect Class.forName failure

Tags: java, class, reflection, syntax, classnotfoundexception

Using:

```
final Class<?> c = Class.forName(path);
```

Here is where the classes exist: http://prntscr.com/juqp7g

This is the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: interfaces/container/InventoryComponentAction
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at scripts.action.ActionManager.init(ActionManager.java:48)
at scripts.system.Application.lambda$0(Application.java:17)
at scripts.system.Application.log(Application.java:29)
at scripts.system.Application.main(Application.java:17)
```

Answer (score 8):

The parameter to `Class.forName` is not a path, but a fully qualified class name (using dots, not slashes).

Instead of what you're doing, try:

```
final Class<?> c = Class.forName("interfaces.container.InventoryComponentAction");
```

or more generally:

```
final Class<?> c = Class.forName(path.replace('/', '.'));
```